# In the context of algorithms what does "bookkeeping scheme" mean?

Tags: algorithms, terminology

In [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.85.2024&rep=rep1&type=pdf), begining of page 5 is written:

> The partial costs are then equivalent to
>   [...]
>   with the bookkeeping entities
>   [...]
>   The bookkeping scheme enable fast evaluation of the cost function.

Briefly, what is a "bookkeeping scheme"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storage of already computed values, so that they do not need to be recalculated when the same calculation is to be carried out.

This is what I would understand by "bookkeeping".